# Matching TV and Movie File names with NLP/Machine Learning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tokenize, text-classification

So i've wondered if there would be a way to tokenize/tag TV or Movie Files using NLP/Machine Learing.

I know there are a lot of regexp approaches out there which do this already but shouldn't it be possible to get this done with NLP/Machine Learning as well?

Example: 
`The.Heart.Guy.S01E07.Die.Belastungsprobe.German.DL.720p.HDTV.x264-GDR`

Should be something like:

`The Heart Guy SHOW-NAME
1 SEASON
7 EPISODE
Die Belastungsprobe EP-NAME
German DL LANGUAGE
720p RESOLUTION
HDTV SOURCE
x264 CODEC
GDR GROUP`

Anyone ever tried something like this? Or any hints where one should start or if it's even possible to get something like this working.

Comment: Customized approaches will be superior, especially if one might use external data (tv databases with episode names and co). Using ML sounds like a waste of time here and you will  need to somehow prepare some learning-set, which will be hard to do.

Answer (score 2):

Machine learning approaches would cost more than rule-based approaches. But if you want to try a machine learning solution the best solution that comes to my mind is to use markov models as the problem has sequential observations and you can handle it with finite state automatas. You can use this [paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~roni/papers/iestruct-aaaiws99.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwiNufeBt-_UAhXMZFAKHdi9D_8QFggcMAA&usg=AFQjCNF7jUhpZUXY2bubDBsKWMLeSJA37w) as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect using regexes is the easiest solution to this, but if you're willing to put in some time **Conditional Random Fields** are also a great solution. [Here](https://open.blogs.nytimes.com/2015/04/09/extracting-structured-data-from-recipes-using-conditional-random-fields/)'s an article about the New York Times using a CRF based model on recipe data.

[image: Example CRF data]

Another example of CRFs on short text is [libpostal](https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal), which extracts parts of postal addresses.

[image]